# Log and control ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rails-routing

Very often, we get hits to non-existing urls like phpadmin.php, admin.php, testproxy.php and so on.

We would like to capture such non exsiting url and avoid raising rails error but a decent 404. What is the best way to achieve this in Rails 4?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the solutions at http://techoctave.com/c7/posts/36-rails-3-0-rescue-from-routing-error-solution